# Underline hover effect is taking the entire space, but it should take only the text space

Tags: html, css

I'm actually trying to add an underline effect on the text when it is hovered

But when I hover on the p element the underline is taking actually the entire space, what I want is the underline should be displayed only within the text not the complete space which is occupied by the text

To do that I actually added a span element and gave the hover effect to the span, but still it is working the same,

Please check the effect I have added the code below, please help, Thanks in advance :)

```css
.underline-effect span:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
  transform: scale(0,1);
}
.underline-effect span:hover:after{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p class="underline-effect">
  <span>Home</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` to your `span` element.

```css
.underline-effect span{
  position: relative;
}

.underline-effect span:after{
 content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
 transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
 transform: scale(0,1);
}
.underline-effect span:hover:after{
    opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p class="underline-effect">
                      <span>Home</span>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `span` needs to have a `position: relative;` that the span's pseudo-element can *relate* to:

```css
.underline-effect span {
  position: relative;
}

.underline-effect span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}

.underline-effect span:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<p class="underline-effect">
  <span>Home</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing what you told it to do. you set the width of the parent element to 100% and that is why your animation hover affect is taking up 100%.

```
    .underline-effect span:after{
    content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 60px;/*changed from 100%*/
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    transform: scale(0,1);
}
.underline-effect span:hover:after{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sc1bmwkm/1/)

EDIT: This will work but the above answer that putting `position:relative` on your `span` is a better solution imho

Answer (score -1):

Span needs a relative position, but another way, you can give border-bottom to span, and padding or line-height that, and when you hover span, border-bottom is shown. I think this way is better.